# Random page stopped working in wamp server

Tags: wampserver, magento2.2, wamp64

I have installed Magento 2 on localhost(On Wamp Server) after the installation. It's working fine few minutes then, after updating some content inside editor of the CMS(Magento 2). Suddenly pages stopped working like "Site can't be reached".

After few refresh site again start working on my localhost. But this problem arises again and again throught my project.

Please help me in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to HTTPS for the admin area and it'll work, no more connection drops

- even without a valid HTTPS certificate.